# Programming Wordpress to send a custom-built form to specified email address

Tags: html, forms, html-email

I have built a custom html/javascript form that I would like to incorporate into my blog. I would like the submit button of the form to send the information to a specific email address. Is there a way I can add that into the html of the form, or is it going to require an outside php file? And if an outside file is needed, please let me know what I need to do.

I have little experience with php, so very clear, basic answers would be much appreciated.

Comment: This really isn't a WordPress issue. You might want to check out how page templates work. http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates

Comment: I would look at specific plugins which require no coding what so ever. [Gravity Forms](http://www.gravityforms.com/) would be my suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I would handle this with [Page Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates), as hinted at by @BrianFegter.  Create a page template that does what you need (there are many PHP/WordPress tutorials out there on how to create pages, process forms, and output data). Once you have your template, create a page, and apply that template to it. Voilà, form processing.  The best way to do this, imo, is to send the form to the current page, and have the page check for the `$_POST` data at the beginning of the load (before you output a form) and either do the processing there or output the form if no data is detected.